# Programatically change display of the sort icon in datagrid column header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I asked this question previously and did not get an answer but now I have more detail.

Basically I want to programatically display the column sort icon in a wpf datagrid column.

I have the following code to do this:

```
private void dtgMain_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            dtgMain.Columns[0].SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        }
```

This seems to set the sort order of the column but when the grid is drawn the icon does not show.

When I add a message box into the method it works fine. My question is twofold. Why would the message box cause the method to work? And how can I get it to work without the use of a messagebox?

This is the method working with the messagebox in it:

```
private void dtgMain_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Here");
    dtgMain.Columns[0].SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
}
```

edit 
Here is the method that is setting the datacontext of the datagrid

```
public void processLoad(string response)
        {
            XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();

            if (provider != null)
            {
                System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(response);
                provider.Document = doc;
                provider.XPath = "/moo/response/data/load/panel";
                dtgMain.DataContext = provider;

            }

        }
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. When I run the code, the arrow appears ascending whether the messagebox is shown first or not. Please could you provide information on what is causing the DataContext of the datagrid to be changed and when that is happening?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I suspect what is happening is that the data layout changes caused by the DataContext update are being completed after your call to set the direction arrow, and it is therefore being erased after you set it. Interestingly, in my case it failed to work even when I put the messagebox in, perhaps because that was hanging up the UI thread while it displayed.

Could you try replacing the line that sets the sort direction with a similar call put on the dispatcher queue:

```
    dtgMain.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        dtgMain.Columns[0].SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

and see if that works?

Comment: This is what I thought was happening. I have tried adding the code you supplied but get "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" on the second (

Comment: Ah, apologies. It seems that the BeginInvoke call is expecting a delegate type, not just a plain lambda. I have edited the code above, so see if it works now!

Comment: Brilliant. Problem solved. Could you give a quick explanation as to why it was behaving that way? Im guessing it was setting column header order, then after that loading the new datacontext, which was effectively creating new columns in the datagrid?

Comment: I don't know for definite what's happening I'm afraid, but I suspect it is because the DataContextChanged event handler is called after the DC is changed, but before the datagrid is drawn again. My guess is that the rendering engine then decides it's a brand new setup, so it resets the SortDirection property to null during the layout phase (would be interesting to try and trap this happening to verify it). If my guess is correct, then the code above fixes this because it postpones our setting of the SortDirection until after the renderer has done its stuff.

Comment: bob unfortunately it doesnt work without a break point on the code u sent me. It looks like the breakpoint was having the same effect as the message box :/

Comment: Urggh... that's not good news. I haven't reproduced your exact circumstances (I'm not sure what causes processLoad), but I did produce something like it and this method fixed it. The only other thing I can think of now is to try lowering the dispatcher priority to defer the operation till everything else has finished, for example at ApplicationIdle. I have modified the answer again to show this..... Hope it works soon!

Comment: looks promising bob. I will test a bit mroe then mark as answer